Как в обработчик события внедрить ранее определенную функцию в aiogram
Всем привет, я новичок в написании ботов, не судите строго за вопрос :)
Подскажите, как в аиогра3 вызвать в обработчике ранее определенную функцию и возможно ли это сделать? По сути приложенный код - заполнение анкеты пользователя с помощью FSM
Как мне обратиться к функции:
async def rost_func(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(f'Введите свой рост в см (если число не целое - введите его с точкой. Например 165): ')
    while True:
        rost_input = message.text
        try:
            rost = float(rost_input)
            if 60 <= rost <= 260:
                if '.' in rost_input and len(rost_input.split('.')[-1]) > 2:
                    await message.reply('❌Ошибка! \nВведите число с не более чем двумя знаками после запятой')
                else:
                    break
            else:
                await message.reply('❌Ошибка! \n'
                      'Введите корректный рост в диапазоне от 60 до 260 см')
        except ValueError:
            await message.reply('❌Ошибка! \n'
                  'Введите число, используя только цифры без иных символов и пробелов')
    return(rost)

В обработчике:
@rForm.message(Form.rost)
    rost = rost_func(message: Message, state: FSMContext)
    await state.update_data(rost=rost)

